# SQL Server 2000 connection failed provider

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Please help me I have SQL Server 2000 installed on server and I try to set this connection string

```
Data Source=SQL-SRV;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User Id=sa;Password=***;
```

when I try to start connection I have this message

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Note that I can access it from odbc

Answer (score 0):

is a connection problem.

Try this from where you run the app, from a command line (with run as administrator)

1st: ping SQL-SRV

If you see TTL Expired msg, is a network problem call a lan admin

2nd: telnet SQL-SRV 1433

your command line window will cleared if success and if fail, see a msg "connectin..." 
check the sql server is running and the firewall config.

Comment: telnet SQL-SRV 1433 failed
what can i do

Comment: the firewall is disabled

Comment: The ODBC works? it can be a provider problem check the connection sting (sqlcli10, the last with 2k compativility) http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2000/